# EXCEL Delete Button on run

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a template excel sheet that has a macro that changes all text to uppercase :

```
Sub MyUpperCase()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("$A$1:" & Range("$A$1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)
    If Len(cell) > 0 Then cell = UCase(cell)
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveSheet.Buttons("UPPERCASE").Delete

End Sub
```

I need the button to delete itself once run however get error 400 when i run the below? the button is names UPPERCASE as well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't replicate - this code works just fine for me. Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: when i step through it just gets to the end. When run in the Excel sheet the error 400

Comment: Huh, weird.  Try changing `ActiveSheet` to the code name for the worksheet the button is on, i.e. `Sheet1.Buttons("UPPERCASE").Delete`.

Comment: nope. exact same!